# How do you convert SQL to LINQ

Tags: sql, linq, converters

```
SELECT fname || ' ' || lname AS name, fage
FROM people
ORDER BY name;
```

How do I convert the SQL code above to LINQ?

Comment: You didn't specify which language so you have C# and VB.net examples. A pretty good example page really.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `let` to order by the column on the anonymous type.

```
var r = (from p in People
         let t = new {
            name = p.fname + " " + p.lname,
            fage = p.fage
         }
         orderby t.name
         select t);
```

Answer (score 0):

if people object contains fname,lname and fage then you can do this

```
people.Select(p=> new {name=p.fname + " " + p.lname,
                       fage=p.fage
                      }).OrderBy(a=>a.name).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
(from p in People
select [Name] = p.fname & " " & f.lname, p.fage order by [Name]).ToList()
```